# Eloquently checking if a user likes an item in a feed

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently listing items in a feed of sorts, this feed displays a list of 'Freestyles' and a count of the amount of likes the freestyle has, I need to basically say whether the user has liked the freestyle in the feed.

What I have tried:

My likes model:

```
class Likes extends Model {

use SoftDeletes;

protected $table = 'Likes';
protected $fillable = ['id', 'userID', 'freestyleID'];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function variantOne()
{
    return $this->beat()->where('TrackVariantID', '1')->first();
}
public function freestyle() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Freestyle::class, 'freestyleID', 'id');
}
public function user() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'userID', 'id');
}
```

}

In my freestyle model:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'Likes', 'freestyleID', 'userID');
}
public function getLike($user) {
    $like = $this->likes()->where('userID', $user)->first();
    var_dump($like);
    return ($like) ? $like : false;
}
```

My controller:

```
        $freestyleLists =  Freestyle::with('users')
        ->with('beats')
        ->with('likes')
        ->where('active', 1)
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);
```

And finally, where I am hitting the getLikes() method:

```
<p>{{print_r($freestyleList->getLike($user))}}</p>
```

The response recieved:

```
NULL 1 (for every freestyle in the feed)
```

I feel as if I am missing something painfully obvious or overlooking the relationship.

Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `user_id` or `$user->id` instead of `$user` in your `where` clause.

Comment: Yeah - It's just for testing purposes atm where I was passing in the value of $user :)

Comment: You should use `with ($this->with('likes'))` as you are trying to `eager load` the result instead of using `$this->likes()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
$like = $this->likes()->where('userID', $user)->first();
```

Try:

```
$like = $this->likes->filter(function ($l) use ($user) { return $l->userID == $user->id;});
```

Then if count($like) > 0 you'll know if the user liked the freestyle.

Comment: Will this work even when my relationships are set up as they are? I have implemented it and  print_r(count($like)); returns 01 for every result, liked or unliked.

Comment: Oh you're getting back an empty Collection object. Try $like->isEmpty()

Comment: $like = $this->likes->filter(function ($l) use ($user) {
            return $l->userID == $user->id;
        });
        var_dump($like->isEmpty()); returns: bool(true) 1 however, if i vardump $l->userID == $user->id; the liked freestyles return false. Thanks for your help by the way.